# Nicer notifications in tray

Tags: c#, .net, windows, trayicon

Do you know any example with nicer notification in system tray? I don`t like standard baloon so maybe there are others free, third-party components I can use?

Thanks

Comment: I found this: http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon 
but I`m not sure if there is a way to use this in winforms application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is another example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx

Comment: It`s really great example but I cannot see license. Do you know If I can use this in commercial projects?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx?fid=13655&fr=26#xx0xx

Answer (score 3):

As a designer, I think I know what you are looking for. You want an outlook like notification (as a mini dialog box), you can see an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/diffusedialog.aspx).

Enjoy.