# how to show notification when program is running background?

Tags: c#, notifications

I want to write a windows application with c#, but I don't know how to show a popup in the corner of screen or in the notification area, or any other way to notify the users.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The question has been already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393928/nicer-notifications-in-tray)

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin: That question's more about re-styling it.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) component's [`ShowBalloonTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx) method. Add a `NotifyIcon` to your form in the Designer, give it a name, and call `myNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip` where you want to show the notification.